# Oracle Return an Array over DBLINK

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

I have a local and remote database connected by database link.

From my local database, I want to make a call as follows:

```
declare
    l_rec REMOTE_PKG.array_type@REMOTE_LINK;
begin
    l_rec := REMOTE_PKG.get_id ( 'test1', 'test1_id' );
    ....process l_rec....

    l_rec := REMOTE_PKG.get_id ( 'tab1',  'tab1_id' );
    ....process l_rec....
end;
```

At Remote, the function REMOTE_PKG.get_id should return an ARRAY OF INTEGERS using following logic: ( the name of table and ID column is dynamic ).

```
  select TEST1_ID from TEST1;
  select TAB1_ID from TAB1;
  etc.
```

The table TEST1 can have upto 1,000,000,000 ( 1 billion ) records. Hence that many IDs will have to be returned in an array to local system.

My question is - is it even possible to do what I am trying ?   The complexities come from

- sending a REF CURSOR over database link
- performance of sending back an array filled with 1 billion numbers
- error handling

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL collections are memory structures and , more importantly, session memory structures. An individual number doesn't take up much memory but a billion of them will most likely blow your PGA limit (unless you have a server with a huge amount of RAM). So putting aside considerations of network traffic, you're not going to be able to instantiate the arrays.

As for what you do instead, that depends on your goals. Why do you need one billion IDs transferred from one database to another?

---

> "Unfortunately - this is what I have been told to do. "

In Oracle the number format has a variable size. [Find out more](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1856720300346322149). So if your IDs run 1 - 1000000000 then your array will be less than 6GB in size. But if your one billion IDs span much larger numbers then your array will take up more space. Maybe your PGA target can cope with that: ask your DBA.

This is the place to start, because it's an absolute barrier: you cannot store more in memory than the RAM available, and that's easy to check.

Comment: Thanks. I had some concerns. Unfortunately - this is what I have been told to do.